# How to select a language from a popup click button in css/html ?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a language selector button on a webpage. The language selector button here is the green settings button as shown below: 
[image]

It will work in way that if I click on the button then the drop-down menu will show up. If the language is already in English then it will ask us to select the French language and vice-versa as shown below:

[image]

[image]

The HTML which I have used for the button is:

```
<span class="label-mobile-languageselector" onclick="myFunction()"><img src="img/SettingsSign.png" alt="LanguageSelector">  
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">English</span>
</span>
```

> I am wondering, how can I display the whole page in English or French after clicking the English or French text as shown above in the 2 images ? At this moment; if I click on "French" text, "English" text is getting displayed on the popup and vice-versa but there is no language conversion.

The CSS which I have used for the button is:

```
/* Popup container - can be anything you want */
.label-mobile-languageselector {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

/* The actual popup */
.label-mobile-languageselector .popuptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: red;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: -55%;
    left: 45%;
    margin-left: -80px;
}

/* Popup arrow */
.label-mobile-languageselector .popuptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -35%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red transparent transparent transparent;
    transform: rotateX(180deg); 
}

/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.label-mobile-languageselector .show {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;} 
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity:1 ;}
}
```

I think (not sure) I need to write a JavaScript code in order to create the popup for it. The JavaScript which I have written in order to create popup is:

```
 function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById('myPopup');
  popup.classList.toggle('show')
  if (!popup.classList.toggle('show')) {
    if (popup.innerHTML == "English") {
      popup.innerHTML = "French";
      popup.classList.toggle('show')
    } else {
      popup.innerHTML = "English";
      popup.classList.toggle('show')
    }
  } else {
    popup.classList.toggle('show');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a new HTML document in the language that you desire.
2. Link to it

e.g. `<a href="/fr/mypage" hreflang="fr" rel="alternate">This document in French</a>`

HTML and JavaScript do not come with translation tools built in.

---

Third party automated translation tools, such as Google Translate, exist … but produce pretty poor results and are best left to users to initiate manually rather than having web authors endorse them.

Comment: Hi Quentin, I already have a Javascript file fr-CA  that contains all the translation. I am not sure how can I invoke it ? Is there any way I can invoke that Javascript file somewhere in the JavaScript code and in the html?